# Cannot install perl module Apache2::Const in ubuntu

Tags: perl, apache, apache2, cpan, apache-modules

I am having problem with installing perl module `Apache2::Const`.

When i am trying to install it using cpan.pm it shows the following error

```
Warning: Cannot install Apache2::Const, don't know what it is.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Apache/2.2.22 ,Perl 5.14.

Comment: Please share the exact command you used

Answer (score 2):

Apache2::Const is part of mod_perl.

If you are using the ubuntu-provided apache, you probably just want to:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this website

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1747708.html

try:

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour on the exact same problem on Ubuntu 12.04, and finally figured it out.  I had already installed libapache2-mod-perl2 :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-perl2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Nonetheless, I kept getting the same error when I tried to install the Apache2::Const module via cpan:

```
$ cpan Apache2::Const
Going to read '/home/jdoe/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 27 Apr 2014 08:29:02 GMT
Warning: Cannot install Apache2::Const, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /Apache2::Const/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I finally figured out that Apache2::Const is **already installed** (in binary I suppose) when libapache2-mod-perl2 is installed:

```
$ perl -MApache2::Const < /dev/null
$
```

Therefore **Apache2::Const is not supposed to be installed using cpan**.